# HTML+CSS Two headers next to each other text vertical align

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

What I need (the orange date alignment):

[image]

What I have:

[image]

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N4gpA/

(Adding code because jsfiddle-only isn't allowed)

HTML:

```
<div class="Box1"><a href="#">
                           <img src="http://imgur.com/CAcW4Yw.jpg">
                               <div class="txtBox1"><h2>2014 02 16</h2><h6>vilniaus KM laimėjo  prieš aisčius - <br> kristupas totoris pataikė tris tritaškius</h6></div></a> 
                     </div
```

CSS:

```
h6{
        display:inline-block;
        padding:0;
        margin:25px 0 10px 25px;
        font-size:24px;
        font-weight:400;

        text-transform:uppercase;
        color:rgb(230,230,230);

    }

    h2{
        display:inline;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        padding:0;
        margin:0px 0 10px 30px;
        font-size:13;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#e6540c;
    }

.txtBox1{
        position: absolute;
        height: 140px;
        width: 100%;
        background:url(http://imgur.com/c9KcXjv.jpg);
        bottom: 0; 

    }


    .Box1{

        float:left;
        width: 703px;
        height: 589px;  
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
        border-radius: 5px;

    }
```

Do I have to play around with boxes and absolute positions again? or there's some easy fix for the vertical alignment?

Comment: Wow, all your questions seem to be about the same thing.

Comment: I'm basically learning from 0 :) If this would be answered on another question that I have asked I would just use that. Just wanted to know if I have to make two boxes and use the absolute/relative again, or it can be aligned easily by using something else.

Comment: That you’re learning is fair and well – but _research_ should play a bigger role in that process. Look into the `vertical-align` property.

Comment: Eh, you should of put that as an answer, I `tried vertical-align:top` and it actually worked (for the first time ever). I had to use `display:inline-block` instead of `display:block` to apply `margin-top` though, is that a 'legit' move? I am basically trying to understand what's 'standard'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your HTML clean. Close all tags.

```
<div class="Box1">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://imgur.com/CAcW4Yw.jpg" />
        <div class="txtBox1">
            <h2>2014 02 16</h2>
            <h6>
                vilniaus KM laimėjo prieš aisčius - <br />
                kristupas totoris pataikė tris tritaškius
            </h6>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I don't advocate doing this, but if the align top fails, then force your positioning.

**NOTE:** I added borders so you can see the space that your H2 and H6 are occupying.

```
h6 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 25px 0px 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #E6E6E6;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
}
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #E6540C;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    top: 25px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

It is much better though to break down your positioning tags as divs, and use H1 - h6 for just formatting of text. Then you don't have to worry about conflicts of native formatting and you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Added some width to your header tags and gave them a `float: left` and `float: right`

[Here is a live jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyhawes/N4gpA/2/)

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align:top` on h2, adjust with `margin-top`